# It is necessary to write a vbs script to run multiple xlam files in one excel instance

Tags: excel, vbscript

The task is to write vbs scripts that:

1. The first vbs script (1.vbs) opens an excel instance and loads the 1.xlam file into the open excel instance.
2. The second vbs script (2.vbs) loads the 2.xlam file into the same excel instance.
3. The next one (3.vbs) loads the same instance of excel 3.xlam and so on.
   I tried a lot, but I have new *.xlam being loaded into new instances of excel, not the previously opened one.
   How to solve a problem?

My loader1.vbs - for load loader1.xlsm

```
   Set omExcel = CreateObject("excel.application") 
   omExcel.Visible = True 
   vmAlertXLSM = omExcel.AutomationSecurity 
   omFile.AutomationSecurity = 1
   vmFile = replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, ".vbs",".xlsm") 
   omExcel.Workbooks.Open vmFile 
   omExcel.AutomationSecurity = vmAlertXLSM
```

This Ok

I need to write loader2.vbs which loads my loader2.xlsm to the same Excel instance so that the functions written in loader1.xlsm and loader2.xlsm can see each other

It doesn't work like that - a new instance of Excel opens:

```
    vmFile = replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, ".vbs",".xlsm")
    With GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     .Visible = True    
     .Workbooks.Open (vmFile)    
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

### Excel Instances

You can open a file in a new instance of `Excel` with:

```
With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    .Visible = True
    .Workbooks.Open ("C:\Test1.xlsx")
End With
```

You can open another file in a running instance with:

```
With GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    .Workbooks.Open ("C:\Test2.xlsx")
    ' Prove that your in the same instance:
    ReDim wbNames(.Workbooks.Count - 1)
    For Each wb In .Workbooks
        wbNames(n) = wb.FullName
        n = n + 1
    Next
    MsgBox "Open Workbooks: " & vbLf & vbLf & Join(wbNames, vbLf)
End With
```

Comment: What is the error and in which line? Try `omExcel.Workbooks.Open(vmFile)`.

Comment: That is what your first step says *... opens an excel instance...*. For the rest of the files use the second approach: you don't need the `prove` part.

Comment: I changed my question - everything is described in more detail there, taking into account your advice

Comment: I did so - I open the second file according to your advice - the second copy of Excel opens
        vmFile = replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, ".vbs",".xlsm")
        With GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
          .Visible = True    
          .Workbooks.Open (vmFile)    
        End With

Comment: I'm using `Office 2019 64bit`. `Excel` is not open. The first script opens the file in a new instance of `Excel`. The second script opens the second file in the same instance of `Excel`. There are two windows, but it's one instance. You could open `Windows Task Manager` and see how many instances of `Excel` are open: every instance has a different `PID`. You can use the `Redim...` part of the second script to get a message box with the currently open workbooks. If it shows the file paths of both workbooks, then they are open in the same instance of `Excel`.

Comment: I am also using 64-bit Office 2019.
Excel is not open for me. The first script opens the file in a new instance of Excel.
The second script opens the second file in a second window ....

I enter my function = Fun1 () in the sheet cell of the first window
it works, but the = Fun2 () function from the second loaded xlsm does not.

In the second boot window, the opposite is true.

I enter the VBA editor - in each of these "windows" only the code of the xlsm loaded into it is visible, and the code of the second file is not ...

So these are different instances of Excel.

Comment: You could try in a new Sub: `Debug.Print Workbooks.Count` in any of the 'instances'. If it is 2, then there is only one instance. Also, have you checked in `Windows Task Manager` (right-click on the Taskbar).

Comment: If I load my xlsm manually - I open Excel, load loader1.xlsm through its menu, then loader2.xlsm, then there is no such problem and both the functions of the first and second xlsm work on the Excel sheet and the code of both is also visible in the VBA code editor window these files.

Comment: Checked in the task manager - there are 2 copies of Excel

Comment: Do they have a different `PID`? If so, which are they (the numbers)?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this is not working. Spent 2 days on the problem ...
I will solve the problem not using VBS, but loading Loader2 from Loader1 with VBA code - so I have no problems, but I wanted to automate loading through an external VBS loader.
It didn't work out ...

Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: I don't know how to look at the PID)))
I'm not a programmer - just retired brain training.

Thanks again, don't waste your time with me, I've already switched to other methods.

Comment: Found how to look at PID)))
They are:
3936 and 8052